# Managed Path error creating host-name site collection

Tags: hnsc, managed-path

I'm trying to create a site collection (search center) on a HNSC web application. When I run the PS command, I get the following error:

> New-SPSite : A site collection could not be created as the provided hostheader managed path does not exist.  Change the URL to use an existing hostheader managed path 
>   or create the missing hostheader managed path prior to calling this command.

We have other site collections created on the web app without issue, but I don't understand why its asking for a managed path in this case - I've tried creating the managed path and re-running but same error. Any ideas?

```
$SearchSite = New-SPSite -Url $NewSearchSiteUrl -Name $SearchSiteTitle -HostHeaderWebApplication "https://hnsc" -Template $SearchSiteTemplate -OwnerAlias $SearchOwnerAlias
```

Comment: What URL are you passing in as `NewSearchSiteUrl`? Can it collide with an existing managed path?

Comment: did you created the hostheader for the site collection or you using the mange path in your url? what is the url?

Comment: url is:

https://site.mycompany.com/search/searchcenter

Also tried:

https://site.mycompany.com/searchcenter

Have tried it with the "search" managed path created and removed. There is also a managed path called "Sites" and it could be created as:

https://site.mycompany.com/sites/searchcenter